# SQL Sum over partition "NOT" by column

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, window-functions

I need to build analytical SQL queries in which the client should specify any metrics(summing of values in a specific column) or dimensions (group by specific columns).

Assume that I have a table with columns `hour`, `dim_a`, `dim_b`, `metric_a`, `metric_b`, `metric_c` with values showed in csv below

```
hour,dim_a,dim_b,metric_a,metric_b
0,A,X,4,4
0,A,Y,4,24
0,B,Y,20,24
1,B,Y,21,35
1,A,Y,4,35
1,C,Y,10,35
2,B,Y,21,30
2,C,Y,3,30
2,A,Y,6,30
```

Take a look at `metric_b`. This metric is always the same if values `hour` and `dim_b` are the same regardless of value of `dim_a`. For example:

```
1,B,Y,21,35
1,A,Y,4,35
1,C,Y,10,35
```

If we select columns `hour`, `dim_b`, `metric_b` and take distinct values table will look like:

```
hour,dim_b,metric_b
0,X,4
0,Y,24
1,Y,35
2,Y,30
```

And by this values all aggregations against `metric_b` should be done

**I would to like run analytical queries over this data grouping by specific dimensions and doing aggregations of metrics with special aggregation when it comes to `metric_b`.**

1. when I want to group by `hour`, `dim_a`, `dim_b`, and see metrics `metric_a` and `metric_b`. Expected result is

```
hour,dim_a,dim_b,metric_a,metric_b
0,A,X,4,4
0,A,Y,4,24
0,B,Y,20,24
1,B,Y,21,35
1,A,Y,4,35
1,C,Y,10,35
2,B,Y,21,30
2,C,Y,3,30
2,A,Y,6,30
```

2. When I want to group by `dim_a`, `dim_b`, and see metrics `metric_a` and `metric_b`. Expected result is

```
dim_a,dim_b,metric_a,metric_b
A,X,4,4
A,Y,14,89
B,Y,62,89
C,Y,13,89
```

Value of `metric_b` is calculated from 89 = 24 + 35 + 30; 4 = 4

3. When I want to group by `dim_b`, and see metric. `metric_a` and `metric_b`. Expected result is:

```
dim_b,metric_a,metric_b
X,4,4
Y,89,89
```

Value of `metric_b` is calculated from 89 = 24 + 35 + 30; 4 = 4

4. And finally when I want to group by `dim_a`, and see metric. `metric_a` and `metric_b`. The expected result is:

```
dim_a,metric_a,metric_b
A,18,93
B,62,93
C,13,93
```

Value of `metric_b` is calculated from 93 = 24 + 35 + 30 + 4

So aggregation of `metric_b` should be a sum of `metric_b` but not taking in the accounts `dim_a` as a grouping column, but taking everything else. Is there SQL syntax that could help me doing this?

What's more I would like to say that these queries are going to be run on AWS Redshift and there are 20 metrics and dimension 16 so 36 columns. And there will be up to 100 billions of rows there.

Comment: I don't follow, sorry. I understand `group by hour, dim_a, dim_b`, as this is a normal aggregation. I don't understand `group by dim_a, dim_b`, because I don't know why it is C,Y,13,89 and not C,Y,13,65. I don't understand `group by dim_b`, because I don't know why it's Y,89,89 and not Y,89,243. I don't understand `group by dim_a`, because I don't know why it's B,62,93 and C,13,93 rather than 62,89 and C,13,65. How do you get to those other numbers that a mere `group by` and `sum` doesn't get? Sometimes your numbers are larger than the sum, sometimes smaller. I don't get it. Sorry.

Comment: If we select columns `hour`, `dim_b`, `metric_b` and take distinct values table will look like:
`(0,X,4),
(0,Y,24),
(1,Y,35),
(2,Y,30)`
And by this values all aggregations against `metric_b` should be done

Comment: Okay, I see. You are suffering from a bad database model. The first thing I'd do is normalize the table (i.e. split it into separate tables) and only then think about how to query the data.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner so you suggest using 2 tables for these queries. But what should be the joining conditions? I should join directly by dimensions values, or rather create additional column (SHA or another hashing algorithm of each dimension) and join by this specific column?

Comment: I don't know what a row in your table actually represents. Judging from the data shown, it seems you have two sets of data: (1) A `metric_a` per `hour` and `dim_a`, (2) A `metric_b` per `hour` and `dim_b`. It seems these two metrices have nothing to do with each other and it's a mistery why they are in the same table row. So you could make this two tables, one with the key `(hour, dim_a` and the attribute `metric_a` and one with the key `(hour, dim_b` and the attribute `metric_b`. But maybe you can even make this one table of dim types (a, b, ...) and one with `hour, dim_type, dim, metric`.

Answer (score 1):

for number 2:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT dim_a
        ,dim_b
        ,sum(metric_a) a
    FROM dbo.Table_2 t
    GROUP BY dim_a
        ,dim_b
    ) a
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT sum(metric_b) b
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT metric_b
            ,hour
            ,dim_b
        FROM dbo.Table_2
        ) t2
    WHERE t2.dim_b = a.dim_b
    ) c
```

for number 3 :

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT dim_b
        ,sum(metric_a) a
    FROM dbo.Table_2 t
    GROUP BY dim_b
    ) a
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT sum(metric_b) b
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT metric_b
            ,hour
            ,dim_b
        FROM dbo.Table_2
        ) t2
    WHERE t2.dim_b = a.dim_b
    ) c
```

for number 4:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT dim_a
        ,sum(metric_a) a
    FROM dbo.Table_2 t
    GROUP BY dim_a
    ) a
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT sum(metric_b) b
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT metric_b
            ,hour
            ,dim_b
        FROM dbo.Table_2
        ) t2
    ) c
```

Comment: you can write your query for aggregation of metric_a in part a. part t2 is fix and in part c just changes where clause

Comment: Yeah this queries could work but first of all `cross apply` syntax is not allowed in redshift.  Secondly, as I have 16 dimensions I will need to do `select distinct metric_b, hour, dim_b, dim_c, dim_d, ...` up to last dimension which will kill the performance of columnar redshift storage engine